# Operation not permitted while trying to run script through crontab - Mac

Tags: macos, unix, cron

I am trying to run a MongoDB backup script in the crontab (MacOS Catalina 10.15.6)

```
*/2 * * * * cd ~/Documents/MongoDB/hourly/ && source hourly_m_backup.sh >/tmp/stdout1.log 2>/tmp/stderr1.log
```

I am getting the error

> /bin/sh: hourly_m_backup.sh: Operation not permitted

The details for the files:

```
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 Sethu  staff  686 11 Sep 19:38 hourly_m_backup.sh
```

I went through a lot of StackOverflow posts. I couldn't get the script to run through crontab. But if I execute the script independently from the terminal, it's working. I even deleted the file and created a new file. Still, I am getting errors from CronTab. Not sure what to do anymore.

------------ Update --------------

I tried running with sudo command

```
*/1 * * * * echo "####" | sudo -S cd ~/Documents/MongoDB/hourly/ && echo "####" | sudo -S source hourly_m_backup.sh >>/tmp/stdout1.log 2>>/tmp/stderr1.log
```

I am getting the error

> sudo: source: command not found

-----------Update ----------

I tried the solution from this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202332/sudo-source-command-not-found), and I implemented this solution

```
*/1 * * * * echo "####" |  source <(sudo -S cat ~/Documents/MongoDB/hourly/hourly_m_backup.sh) >>/tmp/stdout1.log 2>>/tmp/stderr1.log
```

I am getting this error in the "mail"

> /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `(' /bin/sh: -c: line 0:` echo "####" |  source <(sudo -S cat ~/Documents/MongoDB/hourly/hourly_m_backup.sh) >>/tmp/stdout1.log
> 2>>/tmp/stderr1.log'

Comment: Have you tried with `sudo` ?

Comment: Hi @Olha. Please look for the update in the question. I tried implementing your suggestion and I am getting a new error.

Comment: I tried using ./hourly_m_backup instead of source. I got ./hourly_m_backup command not found

Comment: "./hourly_m_backup command not found" -> `chmod +rwx hourly_m_backup.sh` and then `sudo ./hourly_m_backup.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is a bummer. I have to provide Full Disk Access to CRON in Mac.

[image]

Comment: An article about this is at https://osxdaily.com/2020/04/27/fix-cron-permissions-macos-full-disk-access/